# Empty Values apps script google forms

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a trigger onFormSubmit for a google form. I want to know if a particular drop down list has an answer or not. Suppose that I have code of the following form and a drop down list in my form with the name Country2

```
    function onFormSubmit(e) {
    var AnswerObject = e.namedValues();
    var NumCountries = 1;
    if (namedValues("Country2") != // something goes here {
         NumCountries++;
   }
```

Should this value be "" or null or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

> Any value that is not undefined, null, 0, NaN, or the empty string
>   (""), and any object, including a Boolean object whose value is false,
>   evaluates to true when passed to a conditional statement.

Considering the above, try something like:

```
if (namedValues("Country2")) {
     NumCountries++;
}
```